# Vala Compiler Cannot find soup.h from Library Libsoup 2.4

Tags: compiler-errors, vala, libsoup

When i am compiling my program, i always get this error:

```
fatal error: 'libsoup/soup.h' file not found
```

The Compile command i am using is:

```
valac --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg libsoup-2.4 Main.vala
```

My OS is MacOS Sierra 10.12 and when i look into the Vala API Folder, there is a libsoup-2.4 file at: `/opt/local/share/vala-0.36/vapi`

And i have no idea from where this issue is coming.
I already searched on google without success.
Notice the code is just the sample code for vala from: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/LibSoupSample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install libsoup; only the Vala bindings (`libsoup-2.4.vapi`) come with Vala, not the library itself or the development headers.

Notice that the error mentions `libsoup/soup.h` (a C header) being missing, **not** `libsoup-2.4.vapi`; it's actually coming from the C compiler, not the Vala compiler (Vala is transpiled to C, not compiled directly to machine code).